# HTML class with default code

Tags: html, class, web

I'm doing some formatting on a webpage and I'm wondering if it's possible to save a chunk of html code as a class and reuse it.

For example:

I want to change this -

```
<div>
    <hr>
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <a href="oh.jpg" />
    <hr>
</div>
<div>
    <hr>
    <p>Apple</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

To this -

```
<div class="section">
    <p>Item 1</p>
    <a href="oh.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="section">
    <p>Apple</p>
</div>
```

With the same end result of being contained within two horizontal rules.

Is there a way of making a class that isn't just for styling but contains HTML code as well?

Comment: Not possible without using a script on the client side, or changing the HTML output on the server side (depending what platform outputs the HTML code, if its a static file, PHP or something else). It is not the goal of CSS to modify the DOM, it's just adding ergonomical properties to existing nodes. Insert new elements or modify existing ones by script. The eye is not able to distinguish between a HR element and CSS. In your example the simplest way to achieve the desired result would be CSS as mentioned in Rafi's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to what you're describing is the [CSS pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/after-and-before/). You can't insert HTML, but you can insert text or images, or a simple rectangle with `content:"";display:block;`. With some creativity you can pull off [a lot of effects](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-element-roundup/) with just CSS.

So while you can't insert an actual `<hr>` with CSS, you can psuedo-elements to draw one with whatever styles you please:

```
.section:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    border: 1px inset #000;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
}
.section:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    border: 1px inset #000;
    border-width:1px 1px 0 0;
}
```

If you absolutely need to add HTML, you can use Javascript to find all elements with class `.section` and append child elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS

```
.section{
   width : 100%;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
   margin-top : 5px;
}
```

Comment: I know CSS does the same thing, but I want to be able to use preset HTML code.